# How to add additional field in Django REST Framwork Serializer GET return

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to add additional statistics to a working serializer for the Django REST framework:
If I do a GET request for multiple cases, I want to return not only the cases but a statistic about the cases matching the request (without the pagination):

Request:

```
GET /api/cases/?page=1&gender=0
```

What I want is return all matching cases paginated but add statistics over all matching (in this case all female) cases:

```
{
    "count": 10593,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/adrcases/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "stats": {
             "age_mean": 32.212,
             "age_sd": 6.12,
             ...
              }

    "results": [
        {
            "code": "case_001",
            "age": 47,
             ...
```

How can I modify my serializer to add an additional field like the stats field shown above?

```
class CaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = "__all__"

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...



    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer Updated

What you can do here is override your `ListAPIView.list` method, and inject your data into them easily

```
# inside views.py
class CaseListAPI(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CaseSerializer
    queryset = Case.objects.all()
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self._inject_case_stats(response)
        return response

    def _inject_case_stats(self, response):
        # Here you can calculate your data and inject it to response
        all_cases_count = self.queryset.count()
        # you can use self.filter_queryset() to get the filtered result and do the aggregation to get age sum.
        filtered_age_sum = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).aggregate(Sum('age'))['age__sum']
        all_age_sum = self.queryset.aggregate(Sum('age'))['age__sum']
        all_age_mean = all_age_sum / all_cases_count
        # And now you can calculate the mean for the filtered results.
        filtered_age_mean = filtered_age_sum / all_cases_count
        response.data['stats'] = {
            'age_mean': age_mean,
            'filtered_age_mean': filtered_age_mean
        }
```

Answer updater: I added the logic to calculate the **mean** of all filtered results (unpaginated) only against the count of all records count.

Comment: I still have a problem with this implementation: self.queryset returns unfortunately  all cases and not the filtered ones. How can I query the filtered cases?

Comment: That is really simple to do, just give me a minute to update the answer

Comment: @Gurkenkönig check now, I think this might help

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom pagination

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
page_size = 20
# page_size = 2
page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
max_page_size = 1000

def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response({
        'links': {
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
        },
        'stats': {
            'age_mean': 32.212,
            'age_sd': 6.12
        }
        'results': data
    })
```

Then add this class in your view:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

for more information see [custom-pagination-styles](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) .

Comment: I really like your approach. What I'm missing is access to the Django objects in def get_paginated_response, because I still have to calculate the stats and this is difficult with the already serialized data object.

Comment: You can change your serializer class. I write another answer

Answer (score 0):

This is just a concept. You should change this code as you like

```
class Ser1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stats
        fields = ('age_mean', 'age_sd',)


class Ser2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ('__all__')


class MainSer(serializers.Serializer):
    ser1 = Ser1()
    ser2 = Ser2(many=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('ser1', 'ser2',)
```